# Itamaeの自作のResouceが読み込まれない時の対処法

Tags: rubygems, itamae

`jobber`という`cron`の代替ソフトの設定を行える`Itamae`の resource を作ろうとしたのですが、自作リソースの読み込み時点で躓いています。

こちらを参考に plugin をつくり、gem をインストールしたのですが
http://www.hakopako.net/entry/2016/07/04/100000

レシピからの読み出しでが以下のエラーで失敗してしまいます。

```
 % itamae local recipe.rb
 INFO : Starting Itamae...
/Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/itamae-1.9.6/lib/itamae/recipe.rb:130:in `include_recipe': Recipe not found. (jobber) (Itamae::Recipe::NotFoundError)
```

`recipe.rb`の中身は以下のとおりです。

```
include_recipe 'jobber'
jobber do
  command 'foo'
end
```

Gemは正常に認識されて入るようです。

```
gem list | grep itamae
itamae (1.9.6, 1.6.3, 1.3.1)
itamae-plugin-resource-jobber (0.1.0)
```

慣れないことなので何か基本的な見落としをしてる気がするのですが、
エラー原因を特定するためにはどこを見ていけばいいでしょうか？

#### 2016/10/15 追記

`include_recipe`から`find_recipe_in_gem`が喚び出されてるのを確認して、resourceの場合は recipe と違って include の必要が無いことがわかりました。
https://github.com/itamae-kitchen/itamae/blob/master/lib/itamae/recipe.rb

ですが include しないと以下のエラーになってしまうようです。

```
 INFO : Starting Itamae...
/Users/ironsand/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/itamae-1.9.6/lib/itamae/recipe.rb:105:in `method_missing': undefined method `jobber' for #<Itamae::Recipe::EvalContext:0x007fa7f40d1f30> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: 全然詳しくないのですが、「include_recipe 'jobber'」の部分をフルパスで指定してみてはどうでしょうか？
エラーだけ見ると参照ができていないように見えます。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。確かにフルパスを指定すると読み込めるようなのですが、本来は`include_recipe`で読み込めるはずなのに何故読み込めないかがわかりません。itamaeを呼び出した時にgemがロードされていないなどの原因を推定する事はできるんですが、だとしたら gem list で表示されないはずですし…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーが起こるitamaeのソース該当箇所に`binding.pry`を仕込んで調べた所

エラーメッセージが `` undefined method `jobber' `` のため読み込めてないのかと思ったのですが、
適切な数の引数をとっていないと method missing のエラーを出す仕組みだとわかりました。

以下が該当の箇所です。

```
 def method_missing(*args, &block)
    super unless args.size == 2

    method, name = args
    begin
      klass = Resource.get_resource_class(method)
    rescue NameError
      super
    end

    resource = klass.new(@recipe, name, &block)
    @recipe.children << resource
  end
```

from https://github.com/itamae-kitchen/itamae/blob/master/lib/itamae/recipe.rb#L104